# AngularJs cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am tying to access my logged user data in app but i'm getting this error

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Here is my code:

```
public user: User;

ngOnInit() {
  this.authService.user().subscribe((data) => {
    this.user = data;
  });
}
```

and my `authService.user()` function is:

```
user() {
    if (this.isLoggedIn === true) {
      const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        Authorization : this.token.token_type + ' ' + this.token.access_token,
        Accept: 'application/json, text/plain',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      });

      return this.http.post<User>(this.env.USERS_URL, null, { headers })
      .pipe(
        tap(user => {
          return user;
        })
      );
    }
  }
```

**Any idea?**

## update

if i comment `isLoggedIn` i will get

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'token_type' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'token_type' of undefined

while the token is exist in database as my user is logged in

[image: two]

Comment: Well from your snippet, it's pretty clear that inside `user()` that if `this.isLoggedIn` isn't satisfied, you're not returning something that can be subscribed to. Perhaps you wanted to set up a `filter` operator inside the observable you've already got and always return it?

Comment: @miqh if i comment `isLoggedIn` i will get `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'token_type' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'token_type' of undefined` while the token is exist in database as my user is logged in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

here is my final code which solved my problem

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.authService.getToken().then(() => { //check if user has token in DB
    if(this.authService.isLoggedIn) { // check if user is logged
      this.authService.user().subscribe(user => { // return user data
        this.user = user;
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Hope it helps.